# Determination of thermal expansion of a hollow cylinder

Tags: thermodynamics, heat-transfer, thermal-insulation

I have a heater rod inside a brass rod, which is wrapped by PTFE insulation. The dimensions of the assembly are:

- Heater diameter = 9.5 mm
- Brass rod diameter = 25 mm
- Insulation diameter  = 100 mm

When the heater heats the assembly, will the assembly get tighter or looser? The final temperature that the brass rod would reach is 100 °C and the initial temperature is 20 °C.

Answer (score 2):

Plastics have a thermal expansion rate of approximately 5 to 10 times that of metals. The PTFE will expand the most and the brass expansion is about 50% more than a steel heater, so the assembly will get looser.

[Here is a link to a chart of linear expansion coefficients.](http://www.engineeringtoolbox.com/linear-expansion-coefficients-d_95.html) For a 9.5 mm part with 80 °C temperature change, the steel extends .0082 mm, brass .0142 mm and PTFE .0851 mm.

Comment: May I ask you please how did you determine the extension lengths?

Comment: Change in Length (mm), ∆L = C*∆T*L, Mech. Eng. Design p33, C is constant from http://www.engineeringtoolbox.com/linear-expansion-coefficients-d_95.html (read metric column values, not english), ∆T is 80 degrees, L is 9.5mm

Comment: (+1) Good answer. Consider adding your last comment as an edit to your answer.